# Loop object creation

Tags: c#, arrays, oop

I need to have my second nested for loop send the array values to class friends.
I do not know how I would go about this?
Unless I missed something in the class?

```
namespace List
{
    class Program
    {
        public const int ARRAYSIZE = 5;
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] relSend = { "Enter  name", "enter phone number", "enter 2 didigt month dob", "enter 2 digit day dob", "enter 2 digit dob year" };
            string[] In = new string[5];
            string[] answer = new string[10];
            for (int x = 0; x <= 8; x++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < relSend.Length; i++)
                {
                    WriteLine("{0}", relSend[i]);
                    In[i] = Console.ReadLine();
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < In.Length; i++)
                {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Friends
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Phone { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the end of your code?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you mean you want to create an object out of the information collected, that is no problem:

```
List<Friend> friends = new List<Friend>();

for (int x = 0; x <= 8; x++)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < relSend.Length; i++)
    {
        WriteLine("{0}", relSend[i]);
        In[i] = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    friends.Add( new Friend() { Name = In[0]
                              , Phone = int.Parse(In[1])
                              , Month = int.Parse(In[2])
                              , Day = int.Parse(In[3])
                              , Year = int.Parse(In[4])
                              }
               );
}
```

Make sure to validate the input before creating the object! Also, I would suggest to use `string` for a phone number since you would lose the `0` that is the usual prefix. `Month`, `Day` and `Year` might be combined in a single `DateTime`.

Comment: One interesting thing to note here: his class is called `Friends` (which I would rename to `Friend` as well). Currently, this won't compile because of the `Friends`/`Friend` naming difference.

Comment: Okay, since I have OCD on naming conventions, I will keep it `Friend` ;) @Michael

Comment: Might want to update the `List<Friends> friends = new List<Friend>();` to `List<Friend> friends = new List<Friend>();` as well to avoid confusion for OP.

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if you need any explanations:

```
namespace List
{
    class Program
    {
        //Create a dictionary to find out each question is realated to which property.
        private static Dictionary<string, string> questions = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        static void Main()
        {
            questions.Add("Enter  name", "Name");
            questions.Add("enter phone number", "Phone");
            questions.Add("enter 2 didigt month dob", "Month");
            questions.Add("enter 2 digit day dob", "Day");
            questions.Add("enter 2 digit dob year", "Year");
            //Create list of friends
            List<Friends> friendsList = new List<Friends>();
            for (int x = 0; x <= 8; x++)
            {
                Friends f = new Friends();
                foreach (string q in questions.Keys)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}", q);
                    //Find property using Sytem.Reflection
                    System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property = f.GetType().GetProperty(questions[q]);
                    //Set value of found property
                    property.SetValue(f, Convert.ChangeType(Console.ReadLine(), property.PropertyType), null);
                }
                //Add a friend to list
                friendsList.Add(f);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class Friends
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Phone { get; set; }
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public int Day { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: yes that works well but how would I then search through those objects for a name and grab the information associated with that name?      I'm new to classes I would have done this with a 2 damensial array